# How to run a process without Emacs freezing?

Tags: process

When editing TeX files, programming, upgrading packages, *etc.* we often need to perform tasks - such as compiling code or downloading files from internet - that take a long time to achieve. We can do all of them in Emacs, however executing such commands *freezes* the session: is there a way to execute heavy commands in the background, for example using another thread ?

Comment: See the manual node on [asynchronous processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html).

Comment: @Dan You could create an answer from your comment. This would mark this question solved.

Comment: Note, that you should also follow the links at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html. In my opinion the infos on filters and process sentinels are important. I almost always used `start-process` and never `make-process` until now. But, `make-process` definitively looks very interesting!

Comment: @Tobias -- `start-process` is 6 lines long, excluding the doc-string, and it uses `make-process` as its main ingredient.  So the comment about potentially using `make-process` in lieu of `start-process` is somewhat confusing (absent some explanation).

Comment: @lawlist: With "**looks** very interesting" I meant that one has to look at the linked description. One has a lot of more fine control with `make-process`. One can give a sentinel, filter functions and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use process sentinels. Try for example this:

```
(require 'tex-site)
(defun build-view ()
  "Build LaTeX and view if file is dirty. View only otherwise."
  (interactive)
  (if (buffer-modified-p)
      (let (build-proc
        (TeX-save-query nil)
        (LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape -file-line-error %S%(PDFout)"))))
    (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))
    (setq build-proc (TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file -1))
    (set-process-sentinel  build-proc  'build-sentinel))
    (TeX-view)))

(defun build-sentinel (process event)
"Sentinel to run viewer after successful LaTeXing"
  (if (string= event "finished\n")
      (TeX-view)
    (message "Errors! Check with C-c `")))
```

In this case,  when the LaTeX buffer has been modified,  `(set-process-sentinel  build-proc  'build-sentinel)`
runs the build process `(TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file -1)` in the background.
Sentinel functions, here `build-sentinel`, monitor a process running in the background without blocking Emacs. In this case, when `build-sentinel` detects the build process is finished, it starts the PDF viewer.

There are other functions involved, for example `LaTeX-command-style` defines what flavour of LaTeX command you will actually run; but the main point to craft an asynchronous process is in the function setting the sentinel.